# Capital letter in package folder under target folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My project informations are as following :

```
<groupId>com.entreprise.myprofile</groupId>
<artifactId>myProfile</artifactId>
```

When i build my project i have the following structure under the target folder :

```
target > classes > com > entreprise > myProfile
```

(with a capital P) instead of :

```
target > classes > com > entreprise > myprofile
```

As a result (when "automatic build" is on) it keeps building over and over (never stops) thinking it alaways has something not built yet.

If I change the project name to lowercase and generate it from archetype, i don't have the problem.

Then it looks like i have something wrong with a string case somewhere but I can't figure out where it is.

Here is what i've done so far :

- Checking every file for a "myProfile" string with the wrong case.
- Checking every file for a ${artifactId} in the wrong case.
- Checking the maven assembly plugin configuration.
- Checking every package name for a wrong case.

When i do a "Maven install" from eclipse or command prompt i get :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project myProfileBusiness: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \workspace_myprofile\myProfileBusiness\target\filtered-sources\com\entreprise\myprofile\business\services\MyProfileService.java:[12,36] package com.entreprise.myprofile.dao does not exist
[ERROR] \workspace_myprofile\myProfileBusiness\target\filtered-sources\com\entreprise\myprofile\business\services\MyProfileService.java:[34,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class IProfileDataDAO
[ERROR] location: class com.entreprise.myprofile.business.services.MyProfileService
[ERROR] \workspace_myprofile\myProfileBusiness\target\filtered-sources\com\entreprise\myprofile\business\services\MyProfileService.java:[39,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class IProfileDataDAO
[ERROR] location: class com.entreprise.myprofile.business.services.MyProfileService
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Where do you think the problem might be ?

Comment: My package names are all lowercase. But my artifactId is not. Isn't that normal ?

Comment: My bad, I misread the question.  Comment deleted.  (And I don't know the answer to your latest question, sorry.)

Comment: Are you using eclipse maven plugin for building ? If yes try building from maven command prompt mvn compile

Comment: Yes, i'm using the eclipse maven plugin. I tried building from command prompt and i get the same error in eclipse. (Editing question for error stack trace)

Comment: I don't think that it's a problem with Maven. Where is `IProfileDataDAO` class located?

Comment: It is located at : myProfileDAO/src/main/java/com/entreprise/myprofile/dao/IProfileDataDAO.java knowing that "myProfileDAO" is a module project of myProfile.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I renamed a class on windows to change the case of the class. It worked fine on windows, but when I tried to commit to svn I received errors, in my case, for duplicate files.    The way I solved it was to check it out on a linux system, correct the file names and commit back.   Lesson learned.

Comment: Are you sure you checked all the package?  Also of the dependencies?  The `target/classes` just contains your classes as if they were compiled with javac so they represent your package names.

Comment: I did a `File Search > com.entreprise.myProfile` case sensitive with \*.\* pattern and I get 0 matches. I am thinking about generating my project from archetype with lowercase ... :'(

Answer (score 0):

I think you renamed the parent folder of the java file, changing just some upper or lowercase letter in a Windows environment.

If so... simply delete the target folder and rebuild the project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).